# Splitting class functions across multiple cells in Jupyter?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Given the following code:

```
class DTC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None

    def unique(self,Y):
        d = {}
        for i in Y:
            if i not in d:
                d[i]=1
            else:
                d[i]+=1
        return d

    def ent(self,Y):
        freq = self.__count_unique(Y)
        ent_ = 0
        total = len(Y)
        for i in freq:
            p = freq[i]/total
            entropy_ += (-p)*math.log2(p)
        return ent_
```

The above will run if it is place in a single cell in Jupyter Notebook. However, how can I make the class code work if I want it to be split into multiple cells like this:

Cell 1

```
class DTC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None
```

Cell 2

```
    def unique(self,Y):
        d = {}
        for i in Y:
            if i not in d:
                d[i]=1
            else:
                d[i]+=1
        return d
```

Cell 3

```
    def ent(self,Y):
        freq = self.__unique(Y)
        ent_ = 0
        total = len(Y)
        for i in freq:
            p = freq[i]/total
            ent_ += (-p)*math.log2(p)
        return ent_
```

Comment: "will it be possible to break up the function from the class in Jupyter?" - you can test this, it really doesn't take much time

Comment: Sorry, my original question was not phrase properly. Edited the post. Yes, I have already tried this before.

Comment: There are two ways of achieving this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods to split a class definition over multiple cells in Jupyter Notebooks

### Method 1

Doing it the naive way (*exploiting inheritance and over-riding*):

**Cell-1**

```py
class DTC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None
```

**Cell-2**

```py
class DTC(DTC):
    def unique(self,Y):
        d = {}
        for i in Y:
            if i not in d:
                d[i]=1
            else:
                d[i]+=1
        return d
```

**Cell-3**

```py
class DTC(DTC):
    def ent(self,Y):
        freq = self.__count_unique(Y)
        ent_ = 0
        total = len(Y)
        for i in freq:
            p = freq[i]/total
            entropy_ += (-p)*math.log2(p)
        return ent_
```

The thing to note is that this actually creates a hierarchy of classes internally:

```py
import inspect
inspect.getmro(DTC)
# outputs: (__main__.DTC, __main__.DTC, __main__.DTC, object)
```

If you *do not plan to stretch over too many cells*, you can use this method.

### Method 2

Use the package [jdc](https://pypi.org/project/jdc/); more details/docs for [**jdc**](https://alexhagen.github.io/jdc/)

**Cell 1**

```py
import jdc        # jupyter dynamic classes

class DTC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None
```

**Cell 2**

```py
%%add_to DTC
def unique(self,Y):
    d = {}
    for i in Y:
        if i not in d:
            d[i]=1
        else:
            d[i]+=1
    return d
```

**Cell 3**

```py
%%add_to DTC
def ent(self,Y):
    freq = self.__count_unique(Y)
    ent_ = 0
    total = len(Y)
    for i in freq:
        p = freq[i]/total
        entropy_ += (-p)*math.log2(p)
    return ent_
```

This time no hierarchies are formed:

```py
import inspect
inspect.getmro(DTC)
#output: (__main__.DTC, object)
```

Comment: The above has been reproduced from [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1243) from Jupyter's official repository.

Answer (score 1):

A python-only solution:

```py
class OutsourceMethods:
    @classmethod
    def method(cls, f):
        setattr(cls, f.__name__, f)
```

Used as:

```py
class A(SuperA, OutsourceMethods):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10


@A.method
def bar(self, y):
    print(self.x, y)

a = A()

a.bar(20)

> 10 20

b = A()
b.x = 3
b.bar() 

> 3 20
```

It's not *100%* equivalent, but I haven't noticed a different so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `patch` (or `patch_to`) decorators from the fastcore `basics` module.

For example:

```py
from fastcore.basics import patch
```

Cell 1:

```py
class DTC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None
```

Cell 2:

```py
@patch
def unique(self: DTC, Y):
    d = {}
    for i in Y:
        if i not in d:
            d[i]=1
        else:
            d[i]+=1
    return d
```

For benefits over monkey-patching, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75873731/1544154